# UseNa with table using lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I want to use table across all my varibles using lapply but I also want to see any missing data using *useNA*. How do I do it?

```
lapply(test, table)
```

Answer (score 2):

We may specify the arguments - `useNA` takes three choices - "no", "ifany" or "always".  It is mentioned in the `?table`

> useNA controls if the table includes counts of NA values: the allowed values correspond to never ("no"), only if the count is positive ("ifany") and even for zero counts ("always").

```
lapply(test, table, useNA = "always")
```

Or use a lamdba function

```
lapply(test, \(x) table(x, useNA = "always"))
```